# On the undecidability of the existence of odd perfect numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the sum of the divisors of the positive integer $x$.  That is,
$$\sigma(x) = \sum_{d \hspace{0.01in} \mid \hspace{0.01in} x}{d}.$$

For example, the divisors of $28$ are
$$1, 2, 4, 7, 14, \text{and} \hspace{0.05in} 28,$$
and $\sigma(28)=1+2+4+7+14+28=56$.

We now state the:

> **Odd Perfect Number Problem**
>
> There is no odd (positive) integer $N$ satisfying $\sigma(N)=2N$.

Given that no one has found an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) (**OPN**), and given that nobody (as of yet) has proved that there is indeed none, here is my question:

> **(1)** Is the OPN Problem [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem)?
>
> **(2)** What is the **main obstruction** to *proving* that the OPN Problem is undecidable?

**Possible (Philosophical) Answer to Question (2)**  Well, one main obstruction would of course be if the OPN Problem is, in fact, decidable. But how would one then prove that the problem is indeed decidable?  How would one even start?

Comment: (1) We don't know. (2) Look at your own philosopical answer. Also, proving stuff is undecidable is generally hard. (question at the end) One would either prove or disprove it, that's how most things are proven decidable - by deciding them.

Comment: By the way, your questions would be just as sensible if we replaced OPN problem with some other unsolved problem (funnily, my comment could be repeated verbatim). Is there any reason why you suspect OPN problem in particular might be undecidable?

Comment: **Just an opinion**.  You can do a rectangle $ 2\times 28$ with pieces of paper, being subrectangles of such rectangle your divisors. Thus one of **the more ancient problems** in mathematics is if we can explain why or why no can build the corresponding rectangles for a Mersenne prime arbitrarily large. And the other, OPN, is about the existence of rectangles in the odd case: since there are no examples for $N<10^{1500}$ to me seem that there is a geometrical reason for this fact. These problems have few applications. **Is very strange**. Seem the kind of problems to be easy to solve. Thanks.

Comment: @Wojowu, it is *not just* because I suspect it, but more so, since I have read somewhere that some mathematician(s) (from Harvard, if I recall correctly) seem to seriously consider that possibility.

Comment: @user243301, I believe the route you are proposing is via *Egyptian fractions*?  ^_^

Comment: @Wojowu, an additional reason why I suspect that **OPN** is undecidable is the observation that traditional logic arguments either break down or are still unable to rule out either of two mutually exclusive cases, even if I already have the full strength of a biconditional being equivalent to one case.

Comment: I don't know, is only a vague notion, that you can draw rectangles in the plane, for example a prime is a rectangle without subrectangles (Mersenne primes are rectangles with shape $2^p-1$). With respect your question, the problem is that there is a lot of literature written about this kind of numbers (if there is no odd perfect numbers, likes to me a joke because were written about an item that there no exists), example: Touchard theorem was proved by Touchard, also by Holdener. And it is difficult to me understand why a question of this kind should be undecidable.  What's is the meaning?

Comment: @user11235813 Isn't that true for every open problem though? We have not yet been able to prove <statement> nor <negation of the statement>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is potentially undecidable. We don't know.

Note, if it is undecidable, then it is "intuitively" true. If there is an odd perfect number, we'd expect to be able to find it and write a proof that it is odd and perfect. That is our intuition about the natural numbers, and it would be an intuition not encoded in the Peano postulates.

I like to think of undecidability in this case as showing a limit of what induction can do.

Induction, intuitively, allows you to write an outline for an infinite proof. Once you have an induction proof for $P(n)$, you can write proofs for $P(10)$, $P(1000)$, or $P(100000)$ which do not use induction, but just standard deductions.

If there is no odd perfect number (in the "intuitive" natural numbers) then there would be an infinite proof of this fact - you'd just prove in each case that $\sigma(1)\neq 2,\sigma(3)\neq 6,\sigma(5)\neq 10,\dots.$ But if the question is undecidable, what this means is that the limited sort of infinite proof afforded you by induction is not enough to get the same result.

A similar statement can be made about Goldbach's conjecture - if it is undecidable, then it is intuitively true.

What this means is that induction is a fairly blunt instrument, but it is known that any such reasonable axiom scheme is still too blunt too cover all the theorems that might have intuitive infinite proofs.

Now, if there is a statement $P(n)$ of one variable such that we can write a decision process for $P(n)$ for each $n$ (such as this case or Goldbach,) then, if $\forall n: P(n)$ is undecidable, we will never be able to prove it undecidable. It turns out, if we can prove there is no counter-example, then we can prove the theorem is true, so the theorem would not be undecidable.

Comment: You can make the "intuitive" truth into formal truth. I'm pretty sure that PA can prove "if OPN is undecidable in PA, then OPN is true".

Comment: Can we likewise say "if **OPN** is undecidable in ZFC, then **OPN** is true"?

Comment: @user11235813 Yes. In fact, even PA proves that - if something is undecidable in ZFC, it is undecidable in PA, so by what I've said it must be true.

Comment: Sure, but you might not be able to prove OPN undecidable. That would be the sticking point. @Wojowu This means that if it is undecidable, then it is not provably undecidable.

Comment: Of course that's a valid (and important) point - if it's undecidable, then the undecidability might be unprovable.

Comment: Actually, pretty much has to be unprovable. @Wojowu